# How to del a directory using command line?

Tags: git, directory, git-bash, hyperterminal, deldir

I'm using git bash in hyper terminal. By mistake, I did something and now the shell is showing this satement: ~ (master)
I want to remove the master branch. For which, I listed the hidden files using ls -a, now I want to remove this .git/ directory to get rid of the master branch. What command should I use to del this .git/ directory ? Please help!

```html
$ ls -a
 ./                   .gradle/                 Contacts/    IntelGraphicsProfiles/   NTUSER.DAT                                                                                     OneDrive/   'Saved Games'/
 ../                  .pylint.d/               Cookies@     Links/                   ntuser.dat.LOG1                                                                                Pictures/    Searches/    
 .android/            .vscode/                 Desktop/    'Local Settings'@         ntuser.dat.LOG2                                                                                Postman/     SendTo@      
 .AndroidStudio4.0/  '3D Objects'/             Documents/   MicrosoftEdgeBackups/    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TM.blf                                        PrintHood@  'Start Menu'@ 
 .atom/               AndroidStudioProjects/   Downloads/   Music/                   NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms   README.md    Templates@   
 .config/             AppData/                 Favorites/  'My Documents'@           NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms   Recent@      Videos/
 .git/               'Application Data'@       hello/       NetHood@                 ntuser.ini                                                                                     Roaming/

Asus@LAPTOP-NP0DTL13 MINGW64 ~ (master)
$
```

Comment: Deleting a branch does not require deleting *the entire repo*. What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: Your home directory has been initialized as a git repository, which should never be. `rm -rf .git` can fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+home+directory